# Reversing mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

```
function outputscores($mysqlquery,$reverse=false)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlquery))
    {
        echo '<img src="img/date.png" /> ' . date("j M Y",strtotime($row['timestamp'])) . '
        <img src="img/time.png" /> ' . date("H:i:s",strtotime($row['timestamp'])) . '
        <img src="img/star.png" /> '.$row['score'].$_GET["scoretype"].'<br />';
    }
}
```

I need to reverse the array if $reverse is set to true, but PHP says that the `mysql_fetch_array`'s output is not a valid array. Neither is $mysqlquery itself.

Is there any help?

Wow I've asked so many questions today ._.

**EDIT**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $gid LIMIT 25") or throwerror(mysql_error());

outputscores($result);
```

**EDIT2**
Another possible call:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$gid.",users WHERE users.lastcheck < ".$gid.".timestamp") or throwerror(mysql_error());

outputscores($result);
```

Comment: You can ask as many questions as you need, there isn't any limit on those here :). (But there are limits on what can be asked)

Comment: Just a comment on the code - you REALLY should look into security best practices - NEVER pass unescaped variables directly into SQL queries, or output, you application will be vulnerable to SQL/XSS injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Change your sql query to this:

```
$mysqlquery="SELECT * FROM $gid";
```

Change your function to this:

```
function outputscores($mysqlquery,$reverse=false)
{
    if ($reverse==true)
        $mysqlquery.=" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
    else
        $mysqlQuery.=" LIMIT 25";
    $result=mysql_query($mysqlquery);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       //Do output here
    }
}
```

Here, by adding the words `ORDER BY id DESC` you will make the records be ordered in descending order of the 'id' column in your table. By typing `ASC` instead of `DESC` you can have them ordered in ascending order. Also, you can replace 'id' with any other column from your table, for example `timestamp`, `score`, etc.

Edit: Alternatively, you could also make a different function for adding the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` clause to the query. Then you could do something like this:

```
$reverse=false;//or true
$mysqlquery=addOrderBy("SELECT * FROM $gid",$reverse);
outputScores($mysqlquery);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are propably trying to reverse the whole resultset, try something like this:

```
function outputscores($mysqlres,$reverse=false)
{
   $results = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlres)){
    print('I found a result: <pre>'.print_r($row, false).'</pre>'); //debugging purposes
    $results[] = $row;
   }
   if($reverse) { $results = array_reverse($results); }
   foreach($results as $row)
   {
    echo '<img src="img/date.png" /> ' . date("j M Y",strtotime($row['timestamp'])) .    '
    <img src="img/time.png" /> ' . date("H:i:s",strtotime($row['timestamp'])) . '
    <img src="img/star.png" /> '.$row['score'].$_GET["scoretype"].'<br />';
  }
}
```

Oh yes indeed as soulmerge says, you should feed the function a mysql resource and not an actual query. Thus like this:

```
$query = "SELECT field FROM table";
$res = mysql_query($query);
output_scores($res, true);
```

In regard to your comment, make sure your query is actually returning results, test it in phpMyAdmin or something or add a simple print in the while loop as I did above.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in *snip* on line 55

Comment: The records should be reversed in the SQL query itself, its not efficient to loop through the records twice and reverse them through PHP.

Comment: @click Upvote. It woul indeed be faster to have mysql return them in reverse order. However, the OP specificly asked for the array to be reversed.

Comment: IMO he didn't know that the records could be reversed through SQL, but I agree, you could be right

Comment: The query does not necessarily return results so that's an issue there :/

Comment: AH ok, With the new function just remove the print statement from the while and there should be no warnings anymore since $results is now always an Array, even when there are no results.

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right, $mysqlquery should be a mysql query result, not an array. There are two cases where `mysql_fetch_array()` does *not* return an array:

1. Either the parameter is not a query result resource (verify with `var_dump($mysqlquery))`, or
2. There is simply no result (`mysql_fetch_array()` returns `FALSE`).

I hope you're not passing the query itself to `mysql_fetch_array()` as the name of the variable implies. You must call `mysql_query()` before you can fetch anything.

The reversing itself can be done by fetching all rows and calling [array_reverse()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php). Example:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$rows = array_reverse($rows);
```